# Error in downloader

Tags: magento-1.9, error, fatal-error, downloader

I'm getting this fatal error on the download page of my webshop:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'DEFAULT_SCONFIG_FILENAME' in /downloader/Maged/Connect.php on line 167
```

I'm unable to find out where this is going wrong. I alsof emptied the cache and reindexed. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check if the file in downloader/Maged/Connect/Frontend.php exists. If not, it was probably not copied during your server migration or there was an error copying it.

Comment: also try :  after giving full permission to your Magento folder. It may work after that.

Comment: The downloader/Maged/Connect/Frontend.php exists, I also already tried replacing the entire downloader with the original downloader. Giving full permissions to the downloader doesn't work.